# Mockito local variable

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I am using mockito with spring (java 1.8) and I am trying to use a local variable inside my Answer object:

```
public IProductDTO productForMock = null;


@Bean
@Primary
public ICouchbaseDTOProvider mockCreateProductDelegate() {

    CouchbaseDTOProvider mockService = mock(CouchbaseDTOProvider.class);

    Mockito.when(mockService.get(anyString(), ProductDTO.class)).thenReturn((IBaseCouchbaseDTO) productForMock);

    Mockito.when(mockService.getEnvironment()).thenReturn(null);

    Mockito.when(mockService.insert((IBaseCouchbaseDTO) anyObject())).thenAnswer(
            new Answer<IProductDTO>() {
                @Override
                public IProductDTO answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    productForMock = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, IProductDTO.class);
                    return null;
                }
            }

    );

    return mockService;
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Comment: Back up about three steps.  Why are you creating a bean as a mock?

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with your `Answer`. It's generated from this line:

```
Mockito.when(mockService.get(anyString(), ProductDTO.class))
       .thenReturn((IBaseCouchbaseDTO) productForMock);
```

And, as the error explains "This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values". To solve this you need to use a `Matcher` instead of the `ProductDTO.class` value. [`eq`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#eq-T-) should fit the bill:

```
Mockito.when(mockService.get(anyString(), eq(ProductDTO.class)))
        // Here --------------------------^
       .thenReturn((IBaseCouchbaseDTO) productForMock);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:` means:

You can have an expectation containing raw values:

```
 Mockito.when(mockMixer.mix("red","white")).thenReturn("pink");
```

... or you can have an expectation containing matchers:

```
 Mockito.when(mockMixer.mix(startsWith("re"), endsWith("ite")).thenReturn("pink"));
```

... but you can't have a mixture of both:

```
 // Compiles, but will cause runtime exception
 Mockito.when(mockMixer.mix(startsWith("re"), "white").thenReturn("pink"));
```

The fix is to replace the raw value with `eq("white")` -- now you're passing a matcher that looks for parameters equal to `"white"`.